# MYSQL Inserts taking more than 10s to execute

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-8.0

I have an application which mainly deals with two tables.
Table A has details of teachers (no inserts happen to this, as data is prefilled).
Table B has details of students (every-time a new student is enrolled, a teacher is assigned if the teacher is free at the given moment).
Table A has 500 rows of data and Table B has 60k records. Students get enrolled twice a day, at 0600 and 0900 hrs. Maximum students that can enrol is 500 at any given point.

My db instance is running an **8gb aws rds machine (innodb_buffer_pool_size is 5 gb)**, Table A and B has indexes only on id (primary key)

---

The issue: The number of API **insert** request at 0600 is around 300, and there are other API requests that read from db (including tables A and B). Including everything I expect around **1k requests within the span of 10s**. When the requests start flowing in student enrolment happens in less than 40ms, but soon (within 1s) the insert requests takes upto 17s to add entry to table.

---

**Update:** The insert queries happen in parallel. Maximum live connections are around 50 (its in pool), and depending on the application server, I expect at-least 10 inserts concurrently.

---

Comment: Do you insert rows one-by-one? Why you do not insert them in a batch? or at least as solid transaction.

Comment: Let's see the main `SELECTs`; it sounds like there are missing indexes, leading to full table scans of 60K.

Comment: I can insert rows one-by-one only, because its different API calls.
Table B has index on class_id and start_time along with primary key of id, Table A has primary key, subject, which covers all the where clauses on queries